# Install recent ImageMagick on CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, rpm, installation, imagemagick

I'm having a terrible time trying to get a recent version of ImageMagick installed on a CentOS 6.3 x86_64 server. First, I [downloaded] [1](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) the RPM from the ImageMagick site and tried to install it. That failed due to missing dependencies:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libHalf.so.4()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-6.8.0-4.x86_64
    libIex.so.4()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-6.8.0-4.x86_64
    libIlmImf.so.4()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-6.8.0-4.x86_64
    libImath.so.4()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-6.8.0-4.x86_64
    libltdl.so.3()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-6.8.0-4.x86_64
```

I have `libtool-ltdl` installed, but that includes `libltdl.so.7`, not `libltdl.so.4`. I have a similar problem with `libHalf`, `libIex`, `libIlmImf` and `libImath`. Typically, you can install OpenEXR to get those dependencies. Unfortunately, CentOS 6.3 includes OpenEXR 1.6.1, which includes ilmbase-devel 1.0.1. And that release of ilmbase-devel includes newer versions of those dependencies:

- `libHalf.so.6`
- `libIex.so.6`
- `libIlmImf.so.6`
- `libImath.so.6`

I next tried following the [instructions] [2](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/api/#building) for installing ImageMagick from source. No luck there either. I get a build error:

```
RPM build errors:
  File not found by glob: /home/sean/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/ImageMagick-6.8.0-4.x86_64/usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.8.0/modules-Q16/coders/djvu.*
```

I even re-ran `configure` to explicitly exclude djvu and I still get the same error. At this point, I'm pulling my hair out.

What's the easiest way to get a relatively recent version of ImageMagick (> 6.7) installed on CentOS 6.3? Does someone offer RPMs *with dependencies* somewhere?

Comment: I had trouble with this too, not sure if I ever got it to work but you might try: 'yum install libtool-ltdl-devel'

Comment: In CentOS 6.3, `libtool-ltdl-devel` includes `libltdl.so.7`, but ImageMagick requires `libltdl.so.3`. :(

Comment: I wonder if they are similar enough that you could create symlinks from .3 to .7 and fake out ImageMagick so it installs.  total hack move but it might work :\

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't be having these problems... I tried to search for nice, canned binaries of a current version of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). I couldn't find any that didn't have odd prerequisites...

So I spun up a CentOS 6.3 virtual machine and built the [newest ImageMagick SRPM file](http://imagemagick.mirrorcatalogs.com/linux/SRPMS/). You may want to enable the [RepoForge repository (formerly RPMForge)](http://repoforge.org/) as well. The build went without a hitch!

System information:

```
[root@MDMarra ~]# uname -a
Linux MDMarra.localdomain 2.6.32-279.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Oct 16 15:57:10 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@MDMarra ~]# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m

[root@MDMarra ~]# yum repolist
repo id                                       repo name                                                     status
base                                          CentOS-6 - Base                                                 6346
extras                                        CentOS-6 - Extras                                                  6
rpmforge                                      Red Hat Enterprise 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                       4453
update                                        CentOS-6 - Updates                                               820
```

Begin the installation:

```
[root@MDMarra ~]# wget http://imagemagick.mirrorcatalogs.com/linux/SRPMS/ImageMagick-6.8.0-4.src.rpm
[root@MDMarra ~]# yum install bzip2-devel freetype-devel libjpeg-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel giflib-devel zlib-devel ghostscript-devel djvulibre-devel libwmf-devel jasper-devel libtool-ltdl-devel libX11-devel libXext-devel libXt-devel lcms-devel libxml2-devel librsvg2-devel OpenEXR-devel
[root@MDMarra ~]# rpmbuild --rebuild ImageMagick-6.8.0-4.src.rpm
```

These files were generated:

```
Processing files: ImageMagick-debuginfo-6.8.0-4.x86_64
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/ImageMagick-6.8.0-4.x86_64
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ImageMagick-6.8.0-4.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ImageMagick-devel-6.8.0-4.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ImageMagick-djvu-6.8.0-4.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ImageMagick-doc-6.8.0-4.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ImageMagick-perl-6.8.0-4.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ImageMagick-c++-6.8.0-4.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ImageMagick-c++-devel-6.8.0-4.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ImageMagick-debuginfo-6.8.0-4.x86_64.rpm
```

Install the package:

```
rpm -ivh /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ImageMagick-6.8.0-4.x86_64.rpm
```

Check installed binaries:

```
[root@MDMarra ~]# rpm -qlp /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ImageMagick-6.8.0-4.x86_64.rpm| grep bin
/usr/bin/animate
/usr/bin/compare
/usr/bin/composite
/usr/bin/conjure
/usr/bin/convert
/usr/bin/display
/usr/bin/identify
/usr/bin/import
/usr/bin/mogrify
/usr/bin/montage
/usr/bin/stream
```

Check the newly-installed package version number:

```
[root@MDMarra ~]# /usr/bin/convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.0-4 2012-11-07 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

Enjoy!!

Comment: Hrmmm. Interesting. I didn't install djvulibre-devel, libwmf-devel, jasper-devel or giflib-devel when trying to rebuild the RPM. Lemme give that a shot.

Comment: The list of *-devel packages needed to build the RPM were listed in the error I received when I initially ran `rpmbuild` against the SRPM. I could also just upload the resulting file... But I wanted to outline the steps I took.

Comment: See, I mistakenly followed the instructions that told me to rebuild the SRPM first. Somehow that step let me skip the checks for missing RPMs when running `rpmbuild`. Weird. Installing the missing RPMs did the trick! I was able to build the final RPMs and install them without a hitch. Testing showed the binaries worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, I wish there were pre-built binaries for CentOS, but that's another story... :)

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SSHed INTO ME? This is really awkward.

Comment: @MDMarra: You're about to get married. Be thankful for any action.

Comment: You are my hero thanks really , i did installed ImageMagick 6.8.3-6 2013-03-05 Q16 with your steps , how can i add it to php ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ewwhite Have you tried the method with OpenJPEG?

Answer (score 5):

Since nobody mentioned a "hassle-free" alternative, I'm going to add a new answer.

If you don't mind using non-official repositories, you can enable the Remi repo as described here http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en. After that, just type

`yum install ImageMagick-last.x86_64 ImageMagick-last-devel.x86_64`

And you'll get one of the latest versions available, already packaged and with every dependency correctly resolved and handled by yum. No need to recompile anything.

Note: It's not exactly up to date with the version you can find on the official website, but it seems to be no more than 1-2 months behind. For example, at the time of writing the latest official version is 6.8.8 (Jan 12, 2014) while the one I found on the remi repo is 6.8.7 (Dec 15, 2013).

Comment: Or you can download from remi repo as a one-off with `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi install ImageMagick-last.x86_64 ImageMagick-last-devel.x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with CentOS 7.2 and ImageMagick 6.9.3-9. After much trial and error I discovered that 6.9.3-**8** works, while 6.9.3-**9** has dependencies that fail to resolve. Fortunately http://rpm.pbone.net/ found a repository with the older version.

```
IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION=6.9.3-8
# Be warned, 6.9.3-9 does not work; dependencies fail to resolve
IMAGEMAGICK_LIBS_SHA1=c0919e4ef4b7edc1052ef40eef4cc34f7a86341c
IMAGEMAGICK_SHA1=f99eda483850dd116b08e5527d603be2a47db8c4

curl -O ftp://ftp.icm.edu.pl/vol/rzm4/ImageMagick/linux/CentOS/x86_64/ImageMagick-libs-$IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION.x86_64.rpm \
    && sha1sum ImageMagick-libs-$IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION.x86_64.rpm | grep $IMAGEMAGICK_LIBS_SHA1 \
    && yum install -y ImageMagick-libs-$IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION.x86_64.rpm \
    && rm ImageMagick-libs-$IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION.x86_64.rpm \
    && curl -O ftp://ftp.icm.edu.pl/vol/rzm4/ImageMagick/linux/CentOS/x86_64/ImageMagick-$IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION.x86_64.rpm \
    && sha1sum ImageMagick-$IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION.x86_64.rpm | grep $IMAGEMAGICK_SHA1 \
    && yum install -y ImageMagick-$IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION.x86_64.rpm \
    && rm ImageMagick-$IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need the following or at least some of the following:

```
OpenEXR-devel.i686
OpenEXR-devel.x86_64
OpenEXR-libs.i686
OpenEXR-libs.x86_64

yum install OpenEXR-devel.i686 OpenEXR-libs.i686 OpenEXR-devel.x86_64 OpenEXR-libs.x86_64
```

Installing all 4 shouldn't cause that much of a burden or increase in disk space usage, but those are the packages being returned when I searched on http://rpm.pbone.net/ for 'libHalf.so.4' or '  libIlmImf.so.4' for example.

Comment: I'll update my post to clarify, but I already went down that path. CentOS 6.3 has OpenEXR 1.6.1, which includes *newer* versions of things like `libHalf` (`libHalf.so.6` for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the development version of ImageMagicK installed as well, you can run:

rpm -ivh /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ImageMagick-devel-6.8.0-4.x86_64.rpm

This step will be required if you plan to run the ImagicK (PHP) bindings. 
To install iMagicK type:

pecl install imagick