# Problems with ImageMagick 6.8.5 on CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos6, imagemagick

I installed ImageMagick from source per their instructions since they didn't have a matching version for our OS.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php

However, I ran make check and it passes everything up to tests/validate-stream.tap 1, and then it just stops there. I've left it sitting for half an hour and I have to Ctrl+c to get out. What am I doing wrong? What's the best way to uninstall and which version should I be using for CentOS 6.3?

Comment: CentOS comes with ImageMagick 6.5.4. Is this too old for you?

Comment: + you should not consider installing from source on the production server, unless it is for games only. Otherwise if the newest is not supported, which is obviously never is on CentOS, take the newest source with all dependencies and package it into rpm.

Comment: I don't care which version of ImageMagick I use, as long as it works. I did what ImageMagick.org recommended, which was install from source, because they didn't have a version for CentOS 6.3. However, now Linux is looking in /usr/local/bin for identify and convert even though it's uninstalled and I installed the yum version. "identif" gives error "-bash: identif: command not found" while "identify" gives error "-bash: /usr/local/bin/identify: No such file or directory". The yum version installed to /usr/bin, /usr/etc, /usr/lib, etc.

Comment: I discovered how to install the proper way through yum so that it just installs the CentOS version that it recommends. I did have to unmake and remove a few things manually first though; won't be doing that again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Uninstall**

If your build never reached the make install phase, then no files should have been added to the OS. The prefix you used during your configure should specify where files were placed.  If you left it as default, the likely location is /usr/local/bin for ImageMagick binaries.

I recommend using 3rd party RPM repos as a last resort.  If the version included in your OS will work, then use it.

**Install**

To install a newer version, consider using RPMForge or RPmfind.  This an other 3rd party RPM repositories often provider newer versions than included with the OS.

RPM search sites like rpmfind.net and pbone.net can help you find 3rd party RPMS.

If you cannot find something, then build your own RPMs.

[Install recent ImageMagick on CentOS 6.3](https://serverfault.com/questions/446474/install-recent-imagemagick-on-centos-6-3)

Comment: The build reached and moved past the make install phase, however testing failed, and I stumbled upon the fact that I can use yum install ImageMagick, which installs CentOS' 6.5.4 version. This installed into /usr (not /usr/local) but the system looks in /usr/local... even though both are in the PATH.

For instance:
# identify
-bash: /usr/local/bin/identify: No such file or directory
# identif
-bash: identif: command not found

It's looking in two different places for the correct and incorrect command.

Comment: There should be a log from the build --- go through it and remove what it installed manually. Then re-install the CentOS version.  After that log out and back in and it should work from there.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had to do. What a pain!